# Can't start im-chooser in Fedora

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, input-method

I did `im-settings` in fedora, and it gives me the dialog 'unrecoverable error'. So I opened the log, and it says like this:

```
[ 1571218115.984521]: GLib-GIO[8942]: DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
imsettings information
==========================
XINPUTRC: /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d//none.conf
      File: /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d//none.conf
      Size: 110         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: 10307h/66311d   Inode: 2623694     Links: 1
    Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
    Context: system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
    Access: 2019-10-16 17:02:21.298494380 +0900
    Modify: 2019-02-21 17:05:33.000000000 +0900
    Change: 2019-10-16 16:28:52.412973454 +0900
     Birth: 2019-10-16 16:28:52.412973454 +0900
Is DBus enabled: yes
Is imsettings enabled: yes
Is GTK+ supported: yes
Is Qt supported: no
DESKTOP: GNOME
GUESS_DESKTOP: $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
DISABLE_IMSETTINGS: 
IMSETTINGS_DISABLE_DESKTOP_CHECK: 
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
GTK_IM_MODULE: 
QT_IM_MODULE: xim
XMODIFIERS: @im=none
IMSETTINGS_MODULE: none
IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP: yes

[ 1571218117.519613]: GLib[8942]: DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop exists. imsettings is going to be disabled.
[ 1571218123.186807]: GLib[8942]: DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop exists. imsettings is going to be disabled.
```

I googled about few of those messages(for few hours), but it didn't help. 
Um, I just want to change the input method from ibus to uim(since it works better with Korean).
I've never seen any problem in uim with ArchLinux. Everything worked fine. But in Fedora, seems like it's totally a mess.
Any help?